# Magento 2: How to align column in sales order template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

i wanted to align the column for items qty and price so that they can be space out and not grouping together as it is now. Can I know which file shall I edit ( which path ) and how to make the column space out between each other? I only see the last script on my email template is :

{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

Please advise.

[image: Alignment]

Answer (score 4):

you can change your html structure in following path.

```
vendor/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml
```

Please refer 
`vendor/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml`

**Note:** Don't change any thing in core, Make an copy of the file in you theme folder and do your changes
i.e.,

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml
```

So that if you update the version, it will still work

Comment: Hi MeenakshiSundaram R, thanks. But which code shall i change?

Comment: @Graphics to change on html element right? if yes then just copy the `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` and paste it in your theme folder `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/Magento_Sales/template/email/items.phtml` and do your changes

Comment: im not very good in programming. Can you give me an example on how to make the column space out between each other?